# Preventing duplicates rows without a unique key

Tags: mysql

I have a very large (300M rows) table with the columns:

- `date - datetime`
- `uid - byte(16)`
- `event_number - bigint`
- `start_time - datetime`
- `end_time - datetime`

I currently have an index on the date column as well as a unique index on `uid` and `event_number`.

I regularly receive updates on the end time so have an ETL query which uses:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (date, uid, event_number, start_time, end_time )
  SELECT date, uid, event_number, start_time, end_time
  FROM myStagingTable
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE end_time = end_time;
```

I've started to delete outdated data and to do so, most of my tables are partitioned using range partition on the date column, with monthly partitions.

I'd like to set the above table up using the same range based partitioning.

However, this is not compatible with `UNIQUE INDEX` columns that are not part of the partitioning function. So instead, I've tried to replace the above queries with joins and a simple index on the `date`, `uid` and `event_number` instead of a unique one.

```
UPDATE MyTable t 
  INNER JOIN MyStagingTable s ON t.uid = s.uid 
     AND t.event_number = s.event_number AND t.`date` = s.`date`
  SET t.end_time = s.end_time;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpStaging AS 
  SELECT s.date, s.uid, s.event_number, s.start_time, s.end_time
  FROM myStagingTable s 
  LEFT JOIN myTable t on t.uid = s.uid AND s.event_number = t.event_number;
  WHERE t.uid IS NULL;

// then use above insert statement against tmpStaging without the ON DUPLICATE clasuse.
```

However, on some test data of about 2 million rows, this update process took about 15 times as long as the original setup. I cannot see a better approach, but would really like to introduce partitioning to this table.

I'm using MySQL 5.7 on AWS RDS with a somewhat memory limited instance, however, there is virtually no swap memory in use.

Comment: You probably mean `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE end_time=VALUES(end_time)` to set to the new end time value, not the existing one.

Comment: When you you explain , are all fields of the index used?
(Explain Select * from MyTable t 
  INNER JOIN MyStagingTable s ON t.uid = s.uid 
     AND t.event_number = s.event_number AND t.`date` = s.`date`)

Comment: Yes, all the fields in the index are used in the join query.